# Chunk download file from one-drive

Tags: rest, onedrive

I want to chunk download file from one-drive using REST API.
But I am unable to get file content given range. I got total file size without giving below header.

```
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Range', 'bytes=0-3000');
```

I used above header. But response is not getting. Please help me

Comment: What happens when you specify that header? Assuming your file is larger than 3000 bytes it should work

Comment: when you specify that header i didn't get 200 status.There is no response received.

Comment: i got 200 but method is options not GET.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bug in the service. Thanks for reporting it. We're tracking it here: https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-api-docs/issues/95.

The OPTIONS call you see is your browser's automatic CORS preflight request, which it sends to ask the server for permission to make the actual request you're trying to make (a byte-range download). Based on the server's response, the browser can proceed or fail. In this case, the server isn't including 'Range' on the list of headers you're allowed to send, so it fails. We're working on a fix.